# Our own community ads are mis-centred

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Another annoyingly minor design bug, sorry! I'm so glad I don't have to design for designers...

When *our own* community ads are shown (but oddly not the  other non-GD.SE network ones), they're mis-centred like this, flush against the top left of their space:

[image]

...when ideally to match the other ads they'd look something like this (which matches the general network ads):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed, will be live after our next production build.